# understanding output of npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

At times, `npm install` prints following line in the output

`"Using Node version X.Y"`

What does that mean?

Does npm install itself spawns a node process to perform dependency installation? Or is it just echoing node version to inform the user that all dependencies are expected to work with this node version?

Answer (score 0):

It's echoing the node version used in npm's `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.1.0" <-- this
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Medet answered, it retrieve node version from your *package.json* file. After that it shows all the modules it installs, and in the end (in case everything went well) it shows all modules and their deps in a tree like structure.

You haven't asked this but I don't think it'll hurt if I explain how it installs modules because your question is quite broad and in your description you just asked about the version of node.

First of all, it nests dependencies and then install all modules from [NpmJs](http://www.npmjs.com) using queue (reason for long installation time)

Next, it creates a *node_modules* and all the packages go inside that directory.
If you are understanding the concepts of NPM then I will suggest you refer to this [blog](https://scotch.io/tutorials/node-and-npm-version-numbering-guide-and-best-practices)

Comment: Cool. Even before how npm finds dependencies, I wanted to know if it requires a node process to run. I gave it some thought and came to the understanding that as npm is written in javascript, it requires some runtime environment which interprets javascript and converts them into machine instructions. Node.js can provide that runtime environment as it has the V8 engine.